# Apply the Euler method to the following initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Apply the Euler method to the following initial value problem

$$y'=-\sqrt{y}$$  $$y(0)=1$$

with step of integration $h=0.1$.

I am confused because all the questions I have done previously involve variables $y$ and $t$ but this question doesn't.

So I have began by saying $t_0=0$, $y_0=0$ so $f_0=f(0,1)=-1$

$y_1=y_0+hf_0=0+hf_0=0+(0.1)(-1)=-0.1$

So at $t_1=0.1$, $y_1=-0.1$.

Next, $f_1=f(0.1,-0.1)$

$f(t_1,y_1)=\sqrt{-(-0.1)} = 0.3162...$

From here I am a bit concerned the numbers are just a bit silly so I think I have done something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: $t_0=0$, $y(0)=y_0=1$

Comment: Yes I have just noticed that mistake, $y_0$=1, however I still get horrible long decimals for the answers, is this correct?

Comment: this ode is separable, so you could compare your numeric solution to the exact solution. having a long decimal approximation does not imply that the method isn't working.

Comment: @ZZS14: over what range of $x$?

Answer (score 2):

The Euler iteration formula is given by:

$$t_{n+1} = t_n + h, t_0 = 0, y_0 = 1, h = 0.1, 0 \le t \le 1 \\ y_{n+1} = y_n + h f(t_n, y_n) = y_n + 0.1 (- \sqrt{y_n})$$

I chose that range since you did not provide one and the iteration does not explicitly rely on the $t_n's$..

The iterates would be:

- $y_0 = 1$
- $y_1 = y_0 - 0.1\sqrt{y_0} = 1-.1 = 0.9$
- $y_2 = y_1 -0.1 \sqrt{y_1} = 0.9 - .1(\sqrt{0.9}) = 0.805131670$
- $\ldots$
- $y_{11} = 0.232084$

Of course, we can compute the exact solution and compare that against the numerical as:

$$y(t) = \dfrac14 (t^2-4t+4)$$

**Update**

Care needs to be taken using numerical results on this particular problem. See comments for details!

Comment: There is some non-uniqueness here that should be mentioned. Specifically, your solution is correct and unique up to $t=2$; then the solution can stay zero for an arbitrarily long time before "turning back on" and looking like your solution again. This phenomenon is typically not detectable numerically, because the numerical solution will typically never be exactly zero.

Comment: Your other example doesn't satisfy the initial condition. It is also not decreasing at zero, so it can't satisfy the equation itself either. I think WA has an error in giving the solution $(x+2)^2/4$ when asked for this problem.

Comment: Actually, I made an error earlier. Here as the equation is defined the solution *is* actually unique, in that it gets to zero in finite time and then can't "turn back on" because in doing so it would leave the domain of the right side. If we extend the right side to be $-\sqrt{|x|}$ then it can indeed turn back on as I described, resulting in, say, a solution which is $(t-2)^2/4$ on $[0,2]$, $0$ on $[2,3]$, and then $-(t-3)^2/4$ on $[3,\infty)$.

Comment: Ian, thanks for doing a more detailed analysis! I should have paid more attention, rather than just doing the numerical part!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Euler's Method for y'=-sqrt{y}]

Here is the numeric solution (obtained using d-field) compared with an Euler's method solution (obtained using Excel).